# Having to use DelayedTask otherwise LoadMask doesn't show

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5

I am doing a few processes that take time so I want to be able to show a mask, I use LoadMask. Problem is that the code that I want to run seems to run too quick and I presume is blocking the UI to show the mask. The process takes around 4 seconds so I know the mask isn't being enabled and disabled at the same time.

The way I got around this was to use a delayed task, but it kind of feels like a code smell.

Can I do this a different way?

Here is what I have

```
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(win, {});
    myMask.show();

    var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function () {

         ....... // DO MY stuff and eventually do a myMask.hide()

    task.delay(400);
```

It works great but I was wondering if this is the right way to go ?

If I remove the delayedtaks then the mask never seems to display, but the process does work.

Comment: Can you add the code for your task, including the myMask.hide()?

Comment: what is your 4 seconds task? A REST method call?

Comment: I would use a common callback for these processes and global counter equals to number of processes. In callback decrease this counter. As soon as counter is 0 hide the mask. In ExtJs 6 there are promises for these purposes, but as I can see it's not your case.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. So right now, it appears I am doing it right until I upgrade to a later version of Extjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "process" is some kind of local sequential procedure, what you said above is pretty much correct. If your code is running a busy loop it won't relinquish control to the UI "thread" for the browser to redraw.

So you won't see the mask here;

```
mask();
busyLoop();
unmask();
```

But if you do:

```
mask();
setTimeout(function() {
    busyLoop();
    unmask();
}, 1);
```

It gives the browser time to draw before you get into your stuff.